# close form solutions for infinite sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am interested in finding the following infinite sums in order to reparameterize a distribution function.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \theta^{n}q^{n(n-2)/2} $

where $\theta>0$ and $1>q>0$

and

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\theta^{n}q^{n(n-2)/2} $

where $\theta>0$ and $1>q>0$

Comment: I don't think you'll find a closed form for them, unless you accept a formula involving *theta functions* (which see) as a closed form.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into theta functions. Do you know of a good starting reference? I know nothing about them. I am mostly getting stuck with the $q^n^2$ . It is obvious that this converges, but I'm not sure how to find what it converges to.

Comment: Your second series can be obtained by acting with $\theta \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$ on your first series. So that cuts your work in half.

Comment: If you're expecting $\sum q^{n^2}$ to converge to something recognizable, like $\pi$, David, then my point is that that's not going to happen. A good starting reference is Google.